# Unable to use custom alignment with non-sibling views with animation

Tags: swiftui

**Goal:** to have the tapped person in the `ScrollView`/`HStack` align it's centre with the other views using the explicit custom alignment, `CentreScreenAlignment`

**Problem:** currently nothing is happening when I tap on a given person.

**Code:**

```
extension HorizontalAlignment {
    private enum CentreScreenAlignment: AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in d: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            d[HorizontalAlignment.center]
        }
    }
    
    static let centreScreenAlignment = HorizontalAlignment(CentreScreenAlignment.self)
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var centrePt: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { g in
            VStack(alignment: .centreScreenAlignment) {
                ZStack {
                    HStack {
                        Button("Cancel") {
                            // action
                        }
                        .padding(.leading)
                        Spacer()
                        Button("Done") {
                            // action
                        }
                        .padding(.trailing)
                    }
                    Button {
                        // action
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "person.fill.badge.plus")
                            .coordinateSpace(name: "Add button")
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .alignmentGuide(.centreScreenAlignment) { d in
                                d[.centreScreenAlignment]
                            }
                    }
                }
                EmptyView()
                    .alignmentGuide(.centreScreenAlignment) { d in
                        d[.centreScreenAlignment]
                    }
                
                
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(1..<10) { index in
                            Group {
                                if index == self.centrePt {
                                    Button("Patient #\(index)") {
                                        //
                                    }.transition(AnyTransition.identity)
                                        .alignmentGuide(.centreScreenAlignment) { d in
                                            d[.centreScreenAlignment]
                                        }
                                } else {
                                    Button("Person #\(index)") {                                        
                                        withAnimation {
                                            centrePt = index
                                            print(centrePt)
                                        }

                                    }
                                    .transition(AnyTransition.identity)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.padding()
                
                Text("Hello")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: Just as a small note, check out `NavigationView`. You can then add toolbar items which appear at the top, no need for the manual 'Cancel' and 'Done' buttons

Comment: Anyway, I don't think it's possible to scroll `ScrollView` this way. You may have to use `ScrollViewReader`

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do and what you mean by "align it's centre with the other views using the explicit custom alignment...."

Comment: @Anwuna Not entirely sure how it is unclear. When the Person button is tapped, I would like to align the centre of the Person Button with the other two views that I have explicitly applied the custom alignment guide to. So the centre of the Person button would align with the centre of the person.fill.badge.plus `Image` view.